# How can I parse c++ template class using libclang and python?

Tags: python, c++, templates, libclang

I have the following c++ template class:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Data {
 public:
  T t;
};

class A {
};

int main() {
  Data<A> data;
  return 0;
}
```

How can I read member t of Data class ?

Maybe I need to read instantiated class Data (where A another class)

I have the following python code:

```py
if cursor.kind == CursorKind.CLASS_TEMPLATE:
  for child in cursor.get_children():
    print(f'child is {repr(child)}')
```

But in children I observe only template parameter T and not t member ... !?

Is there some way to read member of template class with all types ?